# How to generate random positive and negative numbers in Java

Tags: java, random, numbers

I am trying to generate random integers over the range (-32768, 32767) of the primitive data type short. The java Random object only generates positive numbers. How would I go about randomly creating numbers on that interval? Thanks.

Comment: This remind me about Rnd() of VB, it returns value in [0,1) only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/363681/608639)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You random on `(0, 32767+32768)` then subtract by `32768`

Answer (score 24):

```
Random random=new Random();
int randomNumber=(random.nextInt(65536)-32768);
```

Comment: scala> def myNextPositiveNumber :Int = { r.nextInt(65536)-32768}
myNextPositiveNumber: Int

scala> println(myNextPositiveNumber)
-17761

scala> println(myNextPositiveNumber)
-26558

scala> 

scala> println(myNextPositiveNumber)
-17758

scala> println(myNextPositiveNumber)
-823

scala> println(myNextPositiveNumber)
17370

Answer (score 6):

```
public static int generatRandomPositiveNegitiveValue(int max , int min) {
    //Random rand = new Random();
    int ii = -min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - (-min)) + 1));
    return ii;
}
```

Comment: Where are you using rand?

Comment: Let's take, for example, min = 2 and max = 4. 
So in case of lowest random number, let's say 0.001, * ((4 - (- 2)) + 1) = 7 * 0.001 = (int) 0.007 = 0 and then -2 + 0 = -2. So we got -2 when actually the minimum was 2.
Something in this formula went wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Generate numbers between 0 and 65535 then just subtract 32768

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question I know but um....

```
n=n-(n*2)
```

Comment: This won't work. 3 = 3 - (3*2), 3 = -6.

Comment: Wrong. Order of operations.

Comment: Nope, it still wont work. How are you doing the operations?

Comment: 3-(3*2) = 
3-(6) = 
-3

Comment: What's the point of this?  This is just a slow way to write `n = -n`, but with possible overflow in the `n*2`.  Does that overflow do something useful?  With `n=-32768` we'd get `n = +32768`, which is outside the 2's complement -32768 .. +32767 range.

Answer (score 2):

([my double-compatible primitive type here])(Math.random() * [my max value here] * (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1))

example:

```
// need a random number between -500 and +500
long myRandomLong = (long)(Math.random() * 500 * (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1));
```

Answer (score 0):

(Math.floor((Math.random() * 2)) > 0 ? 1 : -1) * Math.floor((Math.random() * 32767))

Answer (score 0):

In case folks are interested in the double version (note this breaks down if passed MAX_VALUE or MIN_VALUE):

```
private static final Random generator = new Random();
public static double random(double min, double max) {
    return min + (generator.nextDouble() * (max - min));
 }
```