# how to generate positive and negative numbers in Java

Tags: java, math, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate random positive and negative numbers in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938992/how-to-generate-random-positive-and-negative-numbers-in-java)

Hello I am trying to create a method in Java to create negative and positive values in Java.

the problem is that I don't know how to get this programmed but I do know the logic.. here is what I tought it should be

```
 Random generator = new Random();

 for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
 {
       System.out.print(generator.nextInt(100) + 1);
       System.out.println();
 }
```

but with the code above I get only positive values and I need values between -100 and 100 but how can I accomplish something like that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use:

```
Random generator = new Random();
int val = 100 - generator.nextInt(201);
```

Or, as JoachimSauer suggested in the comments:

```
int val = generator.nextInt(201) - 100;
```

Comment: Personally I'd use `generator.nextInt(200) - 100`, but that's just a matter of taste.

Comment: Ah thanks alot that was the trick :) didn't know i could substract it like that!

Comment: @JoachimSauer: sure. I think that's better. Will update the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz by the way, you'd better denote the type of generator (i.e. Random) somewhere in your answer. I noticed that it's not written neither in the question nor in the answer =)

Answer (score 10):

The general formula is

```
int val = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
```

Note that `min` and `max` can be negative. (max > min)