# Generating a random number within a range (both positive and negative) in java

Tags: java, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating random number in a range with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-number-in-a-range-with-java)

I'm trying to create a single method to generate random numbers between two numbers, but I want it to work with any of these ranges (inclusive):

```
1 to 10
-5 to -10
-10 to 10
```

Comment: exactly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3938992/668970

Answer (score 0):

Show you some code, it only demo the idea:

```
int myRand(int min, int max) {
    int r = rand();
    int range = max - min + 1;
    return r % range + min;
}
```