# Problems generating random numbers within a range with java

Tags: java, random, numbers

I have tried many different ways to generate random numbers but I can't seem to make a simple nextInt(int min, int max) method that will work on negative and positive ranges.

10 to 20
-10 to 10
-10 to -20

If I get it working for one range, the other doesn't work.

Comment: Can you should us the code you wrote?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating a random number within a range (both positive and negative) in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600421/generating-a-random-number-within-a-range-both-positive-and-negative-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-to-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried?

```
rnd.nextInt(max+1-min)+min;
```

should work as long as `min < max`. If you want max exclusive, remove the `+1`.