# Generating a random number within a range. Without Overlflow. In Java

Tags: java, random

Please do not dismiss this as a duplicate of:
[How to generate random positive and negative numbers in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938992/how-to-generate-random-positive-and-negative-numbers-in-java)

I need to use a Random number generator with a **seed**. So, I used the [java.util.Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class with a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%28long%29) that takes a seed.

```
Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Then I used the solution given in the above thread

```
int randomValue = random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
```

However, the problem with the above solution is that if min is a large negative number and max is a large positive number , **then (max - min  + 1) would result in overflow.**

There should be a better solution out there. Can anyone please point me to it.

Thank you!

Comment: It is, indeed, a duplicate _unless_ you provide more information.

Comment: Hi devnull, I did provide the information why it is not a duplicate. The reason being (max - min + 1) could result in overflow.

Comment: @devnull: unless I'm mistaking, the linked answers don't touch a hypothetical situation that involves `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which looks like a valid concern.

Comment: You could assign the result of max - min + 1 a variable called *range* for example. And then use an if-statement to check if range is negative or too large or whatever causes the overflow

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Joroen. Yes, that's the problem with the solution proposed.

Comment: @Gee858eeG, What do you think I should when the range is negative?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe take Integer.MAX_VALUE as parameter for your Random object. Depends on your application, what is suitable for you.

Comment: I highly recommend you study the Javadoc and source code for `java.util.Random`.  There's wealth of information there that should allow you to handle this easily.  If `max` and `min` are `int`s, then `max-min` _has_ to fit in a `long`, and all you really want to do is generate 64 random bits and then use the technique from `nextInt()` applied to generate a `long` value.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `BigInteger` to avoid `int` overflow. Also you can use

```
new BigInteger(int numBits, Random rnd)
```

to create some `BigInteger` with randomized bits (up to bit specified with `numBits`).

So just calculate how many bits you need (`range.bitLength()` may be useful) check if randomized value is in specified range, so if value is greater than range random again, if everything is OK return randomized value increased by `min`.

Here is some code example

```
public static int myRandom(int min, int max, Random r){
    if (max <= min)
        throw new RuntimeException("max value must be greater than min value: max="+max +", min="+min);

    BigInteger maxB = BigInteger.valueOf(max);
    BigInteger minB = BigInteger.valueOf(min);

    BigInteger range = maxB.subtract(minB);
    do{
        BigInteger result = new BigInteger(range.bitLength(), r);
        if (result.compareTo(range)<=0)
            return result.add(minB).intValueExact();
    }while(true);
}
```

Comment: The resulting random function will probably not be uniform.

Comment: @assylias I am not sure if I understand what you mean by uniform (I am not native English speaker :/ ) but from what I see in documentation of [BigInteger(int numBits, Random rnd) constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-int-java.util.Random-) "*...  **uniformly** distributed over the range 0 to (2^numBits - 1)*" so can you say something more about problem with this code? Did I really made some mistake?

Comment: "*if value is greater than range random again*" => you probably introduce a bias in the distribution by doing that. It may not be an issue for the OP though.